# How to show $(1-x)^n<\frac{1}{1+nx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do I show that this inequality holds for all $x \in (0, 1)$ and $n \in \Bbb N$?

> $$ (1-x)^n<\frac{1}{1+nx}.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving with induction $(1-x)^n<\frac 1 {1+nx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124031/proving-with-induction-1-xn-frac-1-1nx)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078342/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590586/42969

Comment: Put $(1+x)^{-n}$ in between.

Comment: Do you know [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) ?